# Como mantener siempre visible la barra lateral en wordpress para resoluciones de PC

Tags: css, wordpress

Estoy haciendo un portal con WordPress y el tema virtue, y me gustaría que para resoluciones grandes (mas de 992px de ancho) la barra lateral de la derecha (sidebar) se mantuviera fija, y cuando sean menores que aparezca al final (ahora mismo este comportamiento lo hace pero al hacer scroll la barra desaparece)

El estilo en cuestión de la barra lateral es div.sidebar

Si redefino el estilo en los css adicionales del tema de la siguiente forma:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  div.sidebar{ 
    height:100%; 
    position:fixed; 
    width:250px;
  }
}
```

Hace lo que quiero, pero claro, pierdo el estilo original del div.sidebar (estilos de fuente, ancho, alineación, etc).

Es posible añadir los atributos height:100% y position:fixed al estilo original, obviamente manteniendo el resto de atributos?

Gracias

Comment: No me convence eso que dices de perder el estilo original a menos que hayas borrado el estilo original del CSS, o bien hayas quitado el link al css que carga ese estilo original, entonces si es normal que tenga ese comportamiento el CSS

Comment: No he debido de explicarme bien. Los estilos no se pierden en ningún momento. Lo que ocurre es que al poner el fragmento de codigo que he puesto, se sobrescriben los estilos que tiene div.sidebar, por lo que los atributos (ancho, centrado, etc) que tenia el div.sidebar desaparecen, se machacan, y solo hay height, position y width que son los del código de arriba

Comment: ¿Es posible que los "atributos que desaparecen" estén definidos en otra media-query diferente?
Las media queries solo cambian los parámetros que tu definas, no el conjunto de parámetros. Suena muy raro que "desaparezcan atributos". p.ej.:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_bg

Comment: Pues no puedo decirte, he intento mirar dentro de los estilos del tema, pero no he visto nada. de todas las formas el ultimo comentario me ha servido, asi lo pones como respuesta te lo puntuo. Gracias

Comment: es muy fácil, mira con el inspector de Google Chrome el estilo que te muestra cuando SÍ aparecen los estilos que "desaparecen" y busca en la ventana de los estilos si aparece algo del tipo: @media